# How can I logout on the server with ASP.NET Core Identity with cookie authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, session-cookies

I'm using a `net5.0` project with `5.0.1` Microsoft packages.

When a user signs out I'm calling `SignInManager.SignOutAsync` to sign them out. This will delete the cookie in the browser. If you save that cookie before you sign out, you're able to put the cookie back in the browser, or a completely different browser, and you're authenticated again.

Is there a way to sign out on the server so that if the cookie is used after a sign out, it won't be valid anymore?

There must be something besides the cookie on the server because if you restart the server, the cookie no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie has a unique identifier(sessionid) for the current session, which is used to uniquely identify a browser with session data on the server.

Normally, session will lost when server restart, so the cookie will be invalid.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without restarting the server?